# Reliable way to get user domain from SPUser

Tags: spuser, domain, claims

I feel a bit silly that I can't think of a reliable way to get this information.

Most `SPUser`s, but not all, now have claims `LoginName`s. This makes parsing the domain name a little bit tricky. Is there a clear method somewhere that doesn't care whether they are claims or regular domain\username?

I have found the `SPClaimProviderManager` type, which does help, but I would have thought there would be an easier way to extract this information.

Thanks